# Unable to diagnose a display related issue

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, motherboard, resolution

I am facing a strange issue with my PC. I have had the resolution set to **2560 x 1440** on my display for as long as I can remember.

I came back after a month away from home and when I turned my PC on, everything was fine. After a few moments, my display went bonkers!

I did a Windows Update in-between. I have attached images below of what I see at the **2560 x 1440** resolution and what I see at **1920 x 1080**.

Please help me figure out this issue.

My current PC build is as follows:

- Asus P9X79 Deluxe motherboard
- 16GB of RAM
- Dell 27" U2713HM monitor
- Radeon 6950HD graphic card
- Core i7 3930k CPU

I have had the above build since 2012. Everything has been working well until this issue occurred. Once I set the resolution to **1920 x 1080**, everything is fine. Anything over this causes the issue in the image.

### @ 2560 x 1440

[image]

### @ 1920 x 1080

[image]

I have tried the following solutions but nothing has worked:

- Changed the DVI-D cable
- Tried a HDMI cable
- Changed the monitor
- Changed the graphics card

Is this a motherboard issue or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would verify these things:

- Try a different monitor, if you have another that supports the problem resolution. Or if you have another computer you can test that monitor on at the problem resolution.
- Reinstall your graphics drivers, in the event they have become corrupted.
- Check your DVI/VGA/HDMI cables, and if necessary reseat your graphics card.

More than likely if you've checked everything, it is a driver issue. Especially if both of the graphics cards you tried were ATI, as they use the same Catalyst drivers.

Comment: Yes this is happening only at resolutions above 1920x1080. Which means it is happening at 1900x1200 and 2560x1440

Comment: The other card was an Nvidia GTX 970 model. Could it be that the win10 update that I did as soon as I first started my pc , caused some major driver issue that won't resolve with just a clean driver reinstall?

Comment: Try color management, as it may have gotten changed for an unknown reason. ou can change your computer's color management settings by opening Color Management in Control Panel.

Open Color Management by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Hardware and Sound, and then clicking Color Management.

Comment: There should be an actual "color profile" make sure that it's not set to inverted colors or anything.

Comment: Checked that. Couldn't find any reference to any inverted colors. I tried calibrating the display and it returned with an "Unspecified error"

Comment: As unusual as it may be, it may be the update you just installed. Check your update history and uninstall the most recent one and see if that corrects the problem.

Comment: I just tried a DisplayPort cable and it is now working at 2560x1440 absolutely fine. Does this mean the issue lies with the DVI cables that I had or the DVI port on the monitor?

Comment: It could be either.